# Laplace equation for a ring (Separation of variables)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I need to solve Laplace equation in a circular ring of radius $a\le r \le b $ with conditions $$u(a,\theta)=f(\theta),\space \space \space u(b,\theta)=0,$$
and, of course, 
$$ u(r,-\pi)=u(r,\pi), \space \space \space \frac{du}{d\theta}(r,-\pi)=\frac{du}{d\theta}(r,\pi)$$

So with the variable separation system i made
$$u(r,\theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$$
Replacing  $$\nabla^2u=R''(r)\Theta(\theta)+\frac{1}{r}R'(r)\Theta(\theta)+\frac{1}{r^2}R(r)\Theta''(\theta)=0$$
Multipliyng by $\frac{r^2}{R(r)\Theta(\theta)}$
$$\frac{r^2R''(r)+rR'(r)}{R(r)}=-\frac{\Theta''(\theta)}{\Theta(\theta)}=\lambda$$
Now i have the equations
$$(1) \space \space \space \Theta''(\theta)=-\lambda\Theta(\theta)$$
$$(2) \space \space \space r^2R''(r)+rR'(r)=\lambda R(r)$$
I already know that to satisfy (1)
$$ \lambda = 0,\space n^2, \space \space \space where \space \space \space n=1,2,3,...$$
$$\Theta(\theta)=C, \space \space \space \Theta(\theta)=\sin n\theta \space \space \space and \space \space \space \Theta(\theta)=\cos n\theta$$
Consequently, replacing the eigenvalues in (2) i arrived to
$$R(r)=C_2+C_1 \ln r, \space \space \space R(r)=C_3r^n+C_4r^{-n} \space \space \space n=1,2,3,...$$
Now.. if I apply the boundary condition $u(b,\theta)=0$
$$R(b)=C_2+C_1 \ln b=0 $$
$$R(b)=C_3b^n+C_4b^{-n}=0$$
So... what now? Does this means that $C_2=C_1=C_3=0$? So $R(r)=C_4r^{-n}$?

Comment: I'd say it means $C_2=-C_1\ln b$ and $C_3 = C_4 b^{-2n}$ so $$R(r)=C_2\ln\left(\frac{r}{b}\right)$$ or $$R(r)=C_4\left(r^{-n}-\frac{r^n}{b^{2n}}\right)$$

Comment: @J_P : Shouldn't you have $C_1$ on the right of your first $R(r)$?

Comment: You're right, luckily the $C$'s are indeterminate so it doesn't really matter and I can pretend I did that to check whether you were paying attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $b$ is just some constant whose value is set prior to any of your work, not a variable.

Let us suppose, just for a moment, that $b = 1$.  Then your $R(b)$ family is \begin{align*}
C_1 + C_2 \cdot 0 &= 0  \\
C_3 \cdot 1 + C_4 \cdot 1 &= 0  \text{,}
\end{align*}
which just says $C_1 = 0$, $C_2$ is unconstrained, and $C_3 = -C_4$.

Returning to general $b$, you can solve for two constants in terms of the other two and then replace the two solved constants in your $R(r)$ family, which is (up to typos) how J_P got the solution in his comment.

Comment: It was simpler than i thought ha. Thanks to both.